# How to get Last Index Of "%" in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

How to get Last Index Of "%" in a string in .NET ? 
I tried

```
string subString = content.Substring(0, startIndex);
int nextOpeningComment = subString.LastIndexOf("%", 0);
```

**This is always giving me -1.**

Here `subString` I'm getting is:

```
<div id=\"xyz\">  \r\n    <img alt=\"\" src=\"App_Themes/Default/Images/abc.jpg\" />\r\n    <%--
```

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a complete example? (Specifically what are content and startIndex before the start of this code.)

Comment: What are the values of `content` and `startIndex` in this supposed-failing case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because the method searches the string backwards, towards the beginning. By specifying start position 0, you tell it to start at the first character. Unless the first character is "%" it will return -1, regardless of what the rest of the string contains. Use the `LastIndexOf` overload without the start index and you should get the expected result.

Comment: content might have a % in it, but content.Substring(0, startIndex); might not :-)

Comment: Ofcourse I'm confident...it's really not working...is it like "%" is a special symbol and requires some other treatment ??

Comment: WOW !! worked like a charm..I thought it(0) is the start index from where it should start the search.

Thanks Fredrik and thanks everyone...!!!

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for occurrences of `%` but you're starting at position 0 and searching *backwards* from there. There's no `%` character at position 0, and that's why the `LastIndexOf` call is returning -1.

You need to start your search at the end of the string:

```
string subString = content.Substring(0, startIndex);
int nextOpeningComment = subString.LastIndexOf("%");
```

Answer (score 4):

If there is no % in the string, then the return of -1 is expected and By Design.  It indicates that the requested string is not present in the value "subString"

Answer (score 3):

there is no symbols from the end of the string starting from 0 try

```
content.LastIndexOf("%");
```